# How to apply for a UK travel visa and a Schengen visa from the USA, having valid H1B?

Tags: uk, schengen, us-residents

I am currently in the USA with a valid H1B and I want to travel to the UK and Paris. Could you please tell me whether I am eligible to apply for a UK travel visa and a Schengen visa from the USA? If so then could you please share with me the process for this?

Comment: Which Schengen country would you be staying in?

Answer (score 2):

To visit the UK you will need a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa). You can see on its page that you can apply [online](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/account/register).

When you apply online you need to:

- fill in the application form in English
- pay the visa fee online (in most cases)
- print out your form
- book an appointment at a visa application center

You can save your application form and finish it later. For the US an application center would be at a [US DHS application support center](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa) (ASC)

For a Schengen visa, you will have to download the [application form](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/download-schengen-visa-application-form/) and submit it along with all relevant documentation to the embassy or consulate of the country you will be entering first or residing the most days in the trip. The list of documentation would be something like

- passport type photograph
- your passport
- copy of the airline return ticket
- proof of accomodation
- travel insurance
- 6 month bank statement
- detailed itinerary of your travelling days in the Schengen zone

You should check with the embassy if any additional documentation is required or not.

Comment: ..thanks for you reply ...could you please tell me whether there are any travel agency who can help to get the visa or do I need to attend the visa interview in person?

Comment: You can search for a travel/tourism agency in your locality but you will have to appear in person if there are any interviews